# It is ok to store a Thread in a static variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to make sure that I always create only one instance of a Thread so I built this:

```
private static volatile Thread mdmFetchThread = null;

private static object Locker = new object();

public void myMethod(){

    string someParameter = getParameterDynamically();

    lock(Locker)
    {

    // If an mdmFetchThread is already running, we do not start a new one.
    if(mdmFetchThread != null && mdmFetchThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
    {
       // warn...
    }
    else
    {
        mdmFetchThread = new Thread(() => { doStuff(someParameter); });
        mdmFetchThread.Start();
    }
    }
}
```

Is this ok to do or what could be possible pitfalls?

//Edit: As requested below a bit context: `doStuff()` is calling some external system. This call might timeout but I cant specify the timeout. So I call it in `mdmFetchThread` and do a `mdmFetchThread.join(20000)` later. To avoid that I call the external system twice, I created the static variable so that I can check if a call is currently ongoing.

Comment: Assuming you have at least some possibility of calling myMethod from more than one thread you need at least a lock to avoid a race condition between your 'does thread exist' check and your 'create thread'

Comment: Yeah that could potentially happen. What kind of lock would be the best to use here?

Comment: Not sure volatile is appropriate there though, why don't you use a static constructor on the class to create the Thread?

Comment: I need to pass data to the thread during runtime (doStuff() is in reality a bit more). Plus, all this happens as part of an interface implementation which I dont have full control over, so I'm limited in what I can do.

//I edited my code above.

Comment: you can use a [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: Well, OK, why not create the thread once only at startup, organise it's code as a loop with some signal at the top and just signal it to run when you need it to?  A producer-consumer queue is a common choice.  That ensures that there can only ever be one thread and implements the lock/check functionality by eliminating the need for it.

Comment: thanks, I added the lock above.

Comment: @MartinJames I am using this Thread to check for timeout down the road and the producer-consumer is not feasible in my scenario. But thanks for the idea!

Comment: I'm beginning to agree with @MartinJames here.. This feels like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe more about the problem that you are trying to solve, instead of the solution you are trying to use?

Comment: are you using .NET4.5, i.e. are you able to use `async` and `await` keywords? I might have a solution for you using a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a thread in a static variable is OK (if you need at most one such thread per AppDomain). You can store whatever you want in static storage.

The condition `mdmFetchThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped` is racy. You might find it to be false 1 nanosecond before the thread exits. Then you accidentally do nothing. Maintain your own boolean status variable and synchronize properly. Abandon `volatile` because it is more complicated than necessary.

Consider switching to `Task`. It is more modern. Less pitfalls.

Consider using a `Lazy<Task>` to create the singleton behavior you want.

Add error handling. A crash in a background thread terminates the process without notifying the developer of the error.

Comment: //Edit: Just realized that I cant use `Task` since I'm on .NET 3.5 :/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if you are using statics to store state (such as a thread), then you might have a design flaw when attempting to scale out or when trying to manage the lifetime of the object. I usually try to avoid statics whenever possible.

An alternative might be to create a class that only manages a single thread to perform your task as an instance. This class might be responsible for passing data to your Thread or managing the state of it. For example, ensuring it is only run once, stopping the thread gracefully, or handling when the thread completes. If you wanted to scale out, then you'd just create multiple instances of your class each with their own thread that they manage. If you only wanted one, then just pass around a single instance.

If you're looking for ways to make this instance available to your entire application (which is usually the issue people are trying to solve when using static variables), then take a look into patterns like using ServiceContainers and IServiceProvider.